# Ruby 2.1.3 installation in Ubuntu 14.04.1 hang?

Tags: rvm, ubuntu-14.04, ruby-2.1

Anyone has this problem where the installation of Ruby 2.1.3 in Ubuntu 14.04.1 hang (using rvm).

This where it hangs:

```
root@ubuntu:~# rvm install 2.1.3
ruby-2.1.3 - #removing src/ruby-2.1.3..
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: ubuntu/14.04/x86_64/ruby-2.1.3.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for ubuntu.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.1.3 - #downloading ruby-2.1.3, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.1.3 - #extracting ruby-2.1.3 to /usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-2.1.3..........................................................
ruby-2.1.3 - #configuring....
```

The configuring portion just keeps spinning for over 30 mins until I kill it with Crtl-C.

RVM version:

```
root@ubuntu:~# rvm -v
rvm 1.25.31 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]
```

Comment: Same problem on OSX Mavericks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this might do the trick.  It worked for me on OS X.

```
rvm install 2.1.3 -- --with-setjmp-type=setjmp
```

Found the solution in [this rvm issue](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/3050#issuecomment-56666232), which references a [core Ruby installation issue](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10272).

Comment: I see. They probably fixed the issue. I can install ruby 2.1.3 without problems now (actually a few days ago).

Comment: Yeah, it looks like this change was committed a few days ago, so I'm guessing you updated rvm after that happened. :)